# For proving that L is in NPC, why do we reduce a known L' into L and not the other way around?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np

For proving that $L$ is in NPC, why do we reduce a known $L'$ into $L$ and not the other way around i.e. reducing $L$ into $L'$.

Comment: Has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that a problem is **NP** complete is, approximately, saying that there is no good algorithm for it.

Saying that $L$ reduces to $L'$ means, approximately, that one way of producing an algorithm for $L$ is to use an algorithm for $L'$ as a subroutine.

Now, if $L$ reduces to $L'$ and $L$ is has no good algorithm, then we know that $L'$ also has no good algorithm – if it did, then "use $L'$ as a subroutine" would be a good algorithm for $L$, but no good algorithm exists. However, if $L'$ reduces to $L$ and $L$ has no good algorithm, we know that "use $L$ as a subroutine" isn't a good algorithm for $L'$ but so what? There are infinitely many other algorithms and we know nothing about whether those are good or bad.

Comment: The last two lines, I don't know what are you trying to say exactly.. sorry.

Comment: @phantom To show that a problem is difficult, you need to show  that _every_ algorithm is bad. It's not enough to show that just one algorithm (specifically, using $L$ as a subroutine) is bad. (Indeed, every problem has bad algorithms, such as "Count to $2^n$ and then solve the actual problem".)

Comment: But our point here is to prove that L will be verifiable in P time if we can reduce it to L', which we know is in P. So, my question is why can't we reduce L to L', so now instance of L is in L' and we know L' is solvable in P time.

Answer (score 1):

A problem $L'$ is NP-hard if for every problem $A$ in NP there is a polytime reduction from $A$ to $L'$. Part of the logic of this definition is that it implies that if $L'$ is in P then all problems in NP are in P, since the algorithm for $L'$ can be used to solve any other problem in NP via the polytime reduction.

Suppose that we already know that $L'$ is NP-hard, and we want to show that $L$ is NP-hard. Intuitively, we want to show that $L'$ can be solved using $L$, and this is formalized by giving a polytime reduction from $L'$ to $L$. Using the definition of NP-hard, you can show that such a reduction implies that $L$ is NP-hard as well – I suggest you work it out.

Conversely, reducing $L$ to $L'$ implies nothing about the hardness of $L$, since it only shows that $L'$ is at least as hard as $L$. Indeed, if your goal it show that $L$ is NP-complete, then presumably you already know that $L$ is in NP, and this already implies that $L$ can be reduced to $L'$, since $L'$ is NP-hard! So reducing $L$ to $L'$ adds absolutely no new information to the picture.